# Использование union только экономит ценные биты в ОЗУ? Или также дает прирост в скоросте воспроизведения программы?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Есть код по объединению:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union MyUnion{
    short a;
    int b;
    long int c;
};

int main(){
    
    MyUnion U;

    U.a = 5;
    cout<< U.a << endl;
    U.b = 66;
    cout<< U.b << endl;
    U.c = 24;
    cout<< U.c << endl;
    cout<< U.a << endl;
    U.c = 24;
    cout<< U.c << endl;
    cout<< U.b << endl;
}
```

Использование union только экономит ценные биты в ОЗУ? Или также дает прирост в скоросте воспроизведения программы за счет сэкономленных битов ОЗУ или это только чисто теоретически, на самом деле нет разницы по скорости если число сэкомленных битов ОЗУ до 1% от общего потребления памяти?

И также второй вопрос, у меня компилятор  DevC++ дает результат:

> 5 66 24 24 24 24
>
> -------------------------------- Process exited after 0.3357 seconds with return value 0 Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

Хотя по мануалам, в частности C++ на примерах. Практика, практика и только практика. Автор: Орленко, Евдокимов указано что после строки `U.c = 24;` у `U.b` должно быть дефолтное значение, хотя программа сохраняет последнее значение переменой *U.c* для *U.a* и *U.b*. Это специфика компилятора или новый стандарт плюсов?

И что по этому поводу можно почитать?

Comment: Что значит дефолтное значение? Они ж занимают одну и туже память.

Comment: Политика UB  вообще запрещает использование двух елементов Union одновременно. Суть юниона - две переменные по одному адресу. Как правило - union используется для хранения двух и больше разных сущностей в одном адресном пространстве. Например обьект микрочип и обьект ведомость (его параметры) хранить внутри одной переменной. Второй случай "UB-неправильного" использования union - конвертация типов, либо конвертация типов которую напрямую запрещает конвертировать компилятор (например `long[2]` можно конвертировать в `int(closure*)()`)

Comment: Да в одном пространсве три переменные - но тут в видеотутариале прям и говориться что грубо говоря у остальных двух переменных должны быть дефолтные значения: https://youtu.be/6IsGVvNbyOo?t=468

Comment: Там говорится, что в остальных - мусор. А union на практике совсем мало где используется. По большей части в старых С API.

Comment: Да, но в моем случае не мусор - а последнее значение одной переменной...

Comment: в с11 использование union таким образом не есть UB, но там нужно быть аккуратным. И там используют это часто, что бы быстро делать некоторые преобразования (к примеру, 8 байт в 2 int).

Comment: Это мусорное значение которое случайно совпадает с чем-то.

Comment: Там не мусорное значение, а конкретное значение, что можно подтвердить эксперементально. UB - это значит что нет гарантии что на всех компиляторах результат будет одинаков, но в большинстве случаев результат можно предсказать. Например если в `с` записать 1 то в `a` и `b` будет тоже еденица (если интеловкий процессор по крайней мере, тут есть оговорка - зависит от порядка байт на даной машине, и если оптимизатор не решил "упростить" ваш эксперимент и ничего не писать в переменную).

Comment: Прирост производительности даёт выравнивание по границам двойного слова (в 32-битной среде), это делается и без union. Как правило все глобальные и стековые переменные выровняны. Можно компилятор заставить не выравнивать их - тогда будет заметно замедление. Особо прикольно было получить в win98 синий экран смерти если сделать невыровняную-через-страницу чтение-запись int, но это уже в прошлом - сейчас исключение будет обработано, и windows это выполнит - но потратит много времени.

Comment: По поводу бит ОЗУ: https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1793744.html#post9456616